# php str_split encoding ussies

Tags: php, encoding, character, ascii

I kinda tried googling everything i could imagine(

I have a russian string stored in a variable
And i need to put it on image using gd2 library one character by another.
Everything works fine, except putting it 1 by 1.
When i try to split it with str_split, or analogs or char by char or substring, i get something like this:

```
$str = "ку";
$data = str_split($str);
var_dump($data);

    array(14) { [0]=> string(1) "&" 
[1]=> string(1) "#" 
[2]=> string(1) "1" 
[3]=> string(1) "0" 
[4]=> string(1) "8" 
[5]=> string(1) "2" 
[6]=> string(1) ";" 
[7]=> string(1) "&" 
[8]=> string(1) "#" 
[9]=> string(1) "1" 
[10]=> string(1) "0" 
[11]=> string(1) "9" 
[12]=> string(1) "1" 
[13]=> string(1) ";" }
```

I tried like everything i could find, but result is still the same. Hope you can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string contains multibyte characters. The basic PHP string functions only work with single-byte characters. There are special `mb_*` string functions but the `mb_split` function cannot handle your requirements.

So you should use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with the unicode flag:

```
preg_split('//u', "ку", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: I've made something awful but working (array of ord's letter by letter, then using TWO chars in a row).
But your answer is way better and also working. Thank you very much.